# How to construct a "toy" version of Gimli permutation for three (instead of twelve) 32-bit words?

Tags: algorithm-design, gimli

I am interested to see a "toy" version of the [Gimli permutation](https://gimli.cr.yp.to/index.html) for three (instead of twelve) 32-bit words. I see that the "core" sub-permutation of Gimli operates on three 32-bit words, but I don't know how to use it for constructing a 96-bit unkeyed permutation. Is it possible to modify the Gimli algorithm to devise such a function? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://gimli.cr.yp.to/spec.html), the Gimli state consists of four columns of three rows of 32-bit words, for a total of 4 × 3 × 32 = 4 × 96 = 384 bits.  Each Gimli round consist of:

1. a non-linear SP-box applied to each 96-bit column individually,
2. on every second round, a linear mixing step that just swaps the first words of pairs of columns, and
3. on every fourth round, a constant addition step that XORs the first word of the first column with a 32-bit round constant.

Probably the simplest way to reduce the Gimli permutation to 96 bits would therefore be to simply drop all but the first 96-bit column and omit the linear mixing step entirely, as it's the only part of Gimli that actually mixes the columns together.  This will naturally give a 96-bit permutation that should resemble the full Gimli permutation in most respects, other than having a smaller state size.

Comment: I would do a constant addition every round then.

Comment: @Biv: I must defer to your superior expertise here. :) But just out of curiosity, what's your reasoning behind that recommendation? Is it a slide attack avoidance thing, or something?

Comment: I have two questions: 1) The 96-bit SP-box includes a swap of the first and third words. Is this operation required for the 96-bit permutation? Or it can be omitted? 2) How many rounds are needed?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I am worried about symmetry yes. :)

Comment: @lyricallywicked if you remove the swap then you have only a propagation from top to bottom. The swap is required for the security of the scheme as it enable a stronger propagation between the layers. Without it, it would be extremely easy to find fix points.

Comment: @lyricallywicked as for the number of round, this can only be determined by a careful analysis of the differential and linear propagations.

Comment: @Biv: Then my understanding is the following: 1) The input is three 32-bit words (X, Y, Z); 2) XOR the round constant to X; 3) Two parallel rotations for X and Y; 4) Three parallel non-linear operations for X, Y and Z; 5) Swap X and Z; 6) Repeat steps 2–5 for N rounds; 7) The output is a 96-bit concatenation of X, Y and Z. Is this correct?